# Change a attributes datatype - CoreData versioning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I have shipped an application that had some core data changes in the background. I currently have attribute labeled as a string I need it to be a boolean now. Is it possible to change these datatypes with a lightweight migration.

Note. The change was done in the background. No one has any information in this entity yet.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you are using the attribute or not, the data store must conform to the new data model. If not, the app will silently crash on your users, so this is definitely not advisable.

Thus: you will have to use lightweight migration. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) for help.

Comment: I am trying lightweight migration, however, it's just not working. I ended up just removing the attribut and adding a new one with a different name then going back and tweaking my code.

Comment: You still need lightweight migration if you do not want your users to experience a crash.